# AuthenticationStateProvider propagates incomplete identity to WebAssembly with Blazor in .NET 8

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I have a component using auto render mode:

```
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveAuto]
```

I inject the `AuthenticationStateProvider`:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider _auth
```

Now, in my code, if I do something like this:

```cs
var state = await _auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var user = state.User;
var isAdmin = user.IsInRole("admin");
```

When this is ran on the server, `isAdmin` is true when my logged-in user is in the `admin` role. However, on WASM, this is false. Plus, on the server side, the name claim correctly contains the user name whereas in WASM it contains the e-mail address.

Is this still a bug or do I have to tweak some settings to get the correct identity propagated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authentication in Blazor 8 WASM is performed by `PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider` on the server persisting the Identity using the `UserInfo` class to the wasm client via its `PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider`

I achieved this and forced everyone to be an "Administrator" for demonstration/testing purposes as follows:

Updated UserInfo to include Roles

```cs
public class UserInfo
{
    public required string UserId { get; set; }
    public required string Email { get; set; }
    public required UserRole[]? Roles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }
}
```

On the server project update `PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider.cs`

Just below these two lines

```cs
var userId = principal.FindFirst(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType)?.Value;
var email = principal.FindFirst(_options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType)?.Value;
```

I added this to persist the role claims

```cs
UserRole[] userRoles =
    principal.FindAll(_options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType)
    .Select(a=> new UserRole { Name = a.Value })
    .Append(new UserRole { Name = "Administrator" }) // <== remove this
    .ToArray();
```

Then in the client to create the ClaimsIdentity update `PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider.cs`

```cs
public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    if (!persistentState.TryTakeFromJson<UserInfo>(nameof(UserInfo), out var userInfo) || userInfo is null)
    {
        return _unauthenticatedTask;
    }

    List<Claim> claims = [
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userInfo.UserId),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Email), // <== Name Claim Issue
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userInfo.Email)];

    foreach (var role in userInfo?.Roles ?? [])
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
    }

    return Task.FromResult(
        new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims.ToArray(),
            authenticationType: nameof(PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider)))));
}
```

```html
@page "/auth"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

@attribute [Authorize]
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveWebAssembly]

<PageTitle>Auth</PageTitle>

<h1>You are authenticated</h1>

<AuthorizeView>
    Hello @context.User.Identity?.Name!
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="Administrator">
    [Administrator]
</AuthorizeView>
```